# CORS Block Laravel + VueJS Axios

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cors, quasar

I am building my own API with Laravel version 7, though when I make a request to Laravel from vuejs (actually quasar), I'm getting: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
".

Just for a dirty quick fix, I've try to add (to my top bootstrap/app.php file):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

I have also tried to add this to a middleware class like following:

```
return $next($request)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

The error still persists. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: try to send a OPTIONS request type from the same login route from postman or something & check its route, I don't think it is giving a 200, as first the browser sends a options request which should have Access-Control-Allow-Origin header which is saved by browser, then it calls the post method & confirms the request if it matches which in your case should match (you are using wildcard), then post request is allowed by browser thus removing the error

Answer (score 0):

You can handle CORS with set a proxy in vue config

*vue.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
 devServer: {
  proxy: 'http://localhost:8080',
 }
}
```

Comment: Produces error
`* configuration.proxy should be an object:
        object { … }
      * configuration.proxy should be an array:
        [object { … } | function, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)`

Comment: You didn't explain what you write in config file but may [this link](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3) helps you

Answer (score -1):

You should send the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in all your responses from the server.
I do not know Laravel pretty well, but it seems that only options are sending this response header.

You can debug this using your browser. Open the network tab and check if your server is sending the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`within all requests.

Although this should solve the issue, you should remember that, in production, using a wildcard (*) for CORS is a bad practice and should be replaced by a whitelist when deploying your app